# Firefox not able to assume untrusted certificate issuer

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-rc

I am a C# developer and i am using Selenium to test web applications. With the newest updates, firefox is not able to assume untrusted certificate issuer. Firefox does not work regardless, it does not matter what i am trying to do. I am testing on a seperated server via RemoteWebriver. Chrome and internet explorer work fine.

Here is a little snippet of my actual code

[...]

```
var uri = new Uri($"http://{ServerProperties.Address}:4444/wd/hub");
```

[...]

```
               case "InternetExplorer":
                   return new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());
               case "Firefox":
                   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                   profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
                   profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = true;
                   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
                   dc.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile);
                   return new RemoteWebDriver(uri, dc);
               case "Chrome":
                   return new RemoteWebDriver(uri, DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

[...]

Thanks for your help